# Designing a Hadamard matrix design of order 12 using Algebra methods

Tags: systems-of-equations, combinatorial-designs

I am trying to design a Hadamard design of n=12. it takes a lot of times, I want to convert the problem into algebra and I hope the problem become easier to find the values of the matrix.

we have 12 by 12 matrix, all rows and columns have -1s and 1s, and we have the following conditions:

> P1. First row and First column has a value of 1. (this condition is to make the matrix as normalized matrix)
>
> P2. Each row has 3 common of 1s with other rows.
>
> P3. Each column has 3 common of -1s with other columns.
>
> P4. Each row and columns has 6 digits of -1s.
>
> P5. Each row and column has 6 digits of 1s.

so far I have reached row no. 7 and I'm struggling to find the correct values for it, the difficult thing are properties P2 and P3. My technique is build each row based on the previous rows, so each new row must achieve the five properties.

My construction is as following:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1 &1\\\hline
 1  & -1  &  -1 & -1 & -1  & -1  & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1   & 1\\\hline
 1  &  1  & 1   & 1  & -1  & -1  & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1  & -1\\\hline
 1  & -1  & -1  & 1  & 1   & 1   & -1 & 1 & -1&  1 & -1  & -1\\\hline
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1  & -1 & -1  & 1 & -1&-1& 1&  1  &-1\\\hline
 1 & 1 & -1 & -1  & -1 & 1  & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1& -1 &1\\\hline 
  &  &  &   &  &   &  &  &  & &  &\\\hline
\end{array}

Now in order to find the values of 7th row, then I did the following: Suppose i is the ith row and j is the column in matrix. The number of -1s in jth column is denoted by y_j, so for example in column no. 12, we have -1s in rows $x_2, x_3, x_4$ so we write the following formula: $y_{12} = x_2 + x_3 + x_4$. Now, if we continue to do the same for all columns, we have following formulas

$x_1 + x_3 = y_2$

$x_1 +x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = y_3$

$x_1 + x_5 = y_4$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 = y_5$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = y_7$

$x_4 = y_8$

$x_3+x_4+x_5=y_9$

$x_2+x_5 = y_{10}$

$x_2 + x_3 + x_5 = y_{11}$

$x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = y_{12}$

Now, we want to find 6 of different ys, such that all equal to 3 of each x, i.e.:
$y_i + y_j + y_k + y_l + y_m + y_n = 3x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 + 3x_4 + 3x_5$ where $i,j,k,l,m,n \in \{ 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 \}$
Do you have an idea how to do this in algebra to find i,j,k,l,m, and n so that the equality hold? the number of different possible values is: 11 choose 6 = 462, and of course a lot of these numbers doesn't achieve the properties, do you know to find these ys in easy way?

---

UPDATE: I have reduces the number of possible from 462 to only 30, since we must choose 2,3,4,5,6,7 for three ys and 8,9,10,11,12 for the other remaining ys, so 6 choose 3 = 20 and 5 choose 3 = 10. and checking this number is possible. The reason is that for each new row, we need to choose 3 of ys for first row since first row has -1 from 2 to 7, and so we have 20 possible ways for choosing ys. and the remaining is 3 of ys for other five columns.

Thank you!

Comment: From your title, I thought you meant a matrix of order $12! = 1\cdot2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdots 11\cdot 12\,$ (!)

Comment: As far as I know (which is very little) most Hadamard Matrices occur from ingenious methods, or are the result of brute force computer constructions. In this case, one of [Paley's Constructions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) works since $12 - 1 = 11$ is prime, and the method used quadratic residues ("perfect squares") modulo $11$. Unless you're dead set on your approach, I'd look into Paley here (I think all order 12 Hadamard matrices are equivalent).

Comment: @pjs36 Thank you for your comment. How to use Paley's constructions if we have first rows and first column with 1s.

Comment: As described in the linked Wikipedia article, Paley's construction ends up with $-1$s in column 1 (except in row 1).  This can be fixed by negating all rows but the first.  (See my answer for more explanation.)  About my answer: I'm sorry I didn't directly address your algebraic approach.  I have a bit of trouble following it.  Can you clarify the meaning of the $x_i$ and $y_j$ and explain how your equations arise?  The approach I suggest also involves a bit of algebra, but is simpler, I think, than what you're trying to do.  Let me know if you have questions about it.

Comment: Seconding pjs36's & Will Orrick's suggestion to go with Paley's construction.

Comment: @pjs36 I just did it quickly by Paley's construction. it was really faster 100 times than my idea! But I still want to develop my approach. Thanks for suggestion (Thanks also to WillOrrick and JyrkiLahtonen)

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution.  I've expanded my answer to show how things work out with the method I was suggesting.  If you are interesting in pursuing your original idea, and have any questions, let me know.  I'm still a bit hazy on what values $x_i$ and $y_j$ are allowed to take in your equations.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thanks you a lot, I spend some time to improve your idea to find a design of order 12. I'm really sorry for not editing my question in a good way, I can see that. When I say $y_{12} = x_2+x_3+x_4$ suppose that the first row is disregarded, and therefore you would see that -1 in row no. 2, 3 and 4. In my notes I disregarded the first row since all are 1s. I will modify the question also.

Comment: I've reread your update, and I've realized the reduction from $462$ to $30$ is not correct.  The correct reduction is only from $462$ to $200=20\cdot10$.  

Your analysis has, however, only required that row 7 be orthogonal to rows 1 and 2.  If you also require that it be orthogonal to row 3, then you reduce the number of possibilities to $81=3^4$.  This is derived from the fact that columns 8 and 9 may not both contain $1$ in a given row.  If they both contain $-1$ in a given row, then columns 5, 6, and 7 contain exactly one $1$ in that row, columns 2, 3, and 4 contain exactly...

Comment: ...one $-1$ in that row, and columns 10, 11, and 12 contain exactly one $-1$ in that row.  This means there are $3^3$ possibilities for those nine columns.  If, on the other hand, columns 8 and 9 contain exactly one $-1$ in a given row (which can happen in two ways), then columns 5, 6, and 7 contain exactly one $-1$ in that row, columns 2, 3, and 4 contain exactly one $1$ in that row, and columns 10, 11, and 12 contain exactly one $1$ in that row.  Again there are $3^3$ possibilities for those nine  columns.  So for the row as a whole, there are $(1+2)\cdot3^3$ possibilities.

Comment: The actual number of possibilities is, however, much less than $81$, once you impose the further conditions that row 7 be orthogonal to rows 4, 5, and 6.  In fact, rows 7 - 12 are completely determined from your rows 1 - 6, except for their order.  So there are only six possibilities for row 7.

Comment: @WillOrrick your analysis is really good. You're right when you see it is 200, but what I mean is that I need only to write the 20 for y from 2-7 and 10 possibilities for y from 8-12, then I can analyse easily without writing all 200 possibilities which one is match to other so I get 8 possibilities. There is only one among all 8 that worked out good. I moved to 8th row and I only checked last other possibilities from row 7 since every thing is not working with row no. 7, it wouldn't work also in any other rows. But I get only two solution, one is worked well....

Comment: ... I moved to row no. 9 and here is the problem there is zero possibilities so I knew that my approach is wrong, so first thing come to mind is to cancel first row and start and new analysing because if you cancel one row that doesn't effect anything but at this step I stopped and I moved to do it by your approach but it didn't help either so I do it using Paley's construction which was so helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56362/discussion-between-will-orrick-and-yousefy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your conditions 2-5 apply only to rows or columns other than the first.  Also note that conditions 4 and 5 imply that each of rows 2-12 is orthogonal to row 1 and that each of columns 2-12 is orthogonal to column 1.  Third, note that conditions 2 and 3 imply that any two rows taken from rows 2-12 forms an orthogonal pair, and likewise for two columns taken from columns 2-12.

If you find a solution, and then permute columns 2-11 in any way whatsoever and permute rows 2-11 in any way whatsoever, then you have another solution.  It turns out that this design has a lot of symmetry, which means that these permuted solutions won't all be different from each other.  Even so, the number of solutions is going to be large.  For that reason, it will be helpful to impose a canonical ordering on rows to reduce the number of possibilities.

You may also negate some rows or columns without destroying the orthogonality property of rows or of columns, although your five conditions may no longer hold.  This implies that if you can find a $12\times12$ matrix with elements $\pm1$ and orthogonal rows (and hence columns), then you can obtain your desired design by negating rows and columns as needed so that the first row and column contain only $1$s.  If this is done, your other four properties will automatically hold.  I find it somewhat more convenient *not* to start with a first row that contains only $1$s, but rather to insist that in the first three rows of each column have an even number of $-1$s, which means either three $1$s or one $1$ and two $-1$s.  First prove the following:

1. The first three rows contain equal numbers of the four column types
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},
   $$
   three of each type in the case of a $12\times12$ matrix.  We may accordingly partition the columns into four sets of three.
2. In row $k$, with $k>3$, these four column sets will contain equal numbers of $1$s.

Clearly these properties hold for columns as well as rows.  These observations allow us to put the first three rows and first three columns in a standard form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & - & -\\
1 & - & -\\
1 & - & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & - & 1\\
- & - & 1\\
- & - & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since in each of rows 4-12, the first column set contains one $1$ and two $-1$s, this must also be true of each of the other three column sets obtained from the partition described above.  If you impose the condition that whenever there are multiple equivalent possibilities for next row to be added, the lexicographically minimal choice is taken (with $1$ coming before $-1$), then the rest of the structure is forced by the orthogonality condition on rows.  You can then obtain your design by negating the last six rows and the last six columns.

**Added:** To see how the structure is forced, consider row 4.  It must have one $1$ in each of the four sets of three columns determined by the partition of columns described above.  (The first set of three is already determined.)  To be lexicographically minimal, the order of elements must be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ in each of the three remaining sets of three columns.

Now consider row 5.  It must also have one $1$ in each of the three as yet undermined sets of three columns.  But it must also be orthogonal to row 4.  The inner product of two vectors of length $3$, each consisting of one $1$ and two $-1$s, can only be $3$ or $-1$.  In the first set of three columns of rows 4 and 5 this inner product equals $3$.  The only way to make rows 4 and 5 orthogonal is for the remaining three inner products to equal $-1$.  This means that the remaining $1$s in row 5 cannot coincide with $1$s in row 4.  To make row 5 lexicographically minimal, the order must be $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ in each set of three columns.  At this stage we have
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & -\\
1 & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & -\\
1 & - & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & 1 & -\\
- & - & 1\\
- & - & 1\\
- & - & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

At this point it may be helpful to introduce a shorthand for the three possible length-3 vectors:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & - & -\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow1,\qquad\begin{bmatrix}- & 1 & -\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow2,\qquad\begin{bmatrix}- & - & 1\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow3.
$$
In this notation, rows 4-12 currently contain
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
1\\
2\\
2\\
2\\
3\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Let the elements of this $9\times4$ matrix be $m_{ij}\in\{1,2,3\}$, where $4\le i\le12$ and $1\le j\le4$.  In completing row $k$, we must adhere to two rules:

1. for each $i$ ($4\le i\le k-1$), $m_{kj}=m_{ij}$ for exactly one $j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$; this is needed for orthogonality, as the only way for the inner product of two rows to equal $0$ is for one of the three-column sets to have inner product $3$ and the other three to have inner product $-1$;
2. if there is more than one equivalent way to complete a row, we choose the one that is lexicographically least.

These conditions mean that row 6 must be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.  If we write row 7 as $\begin{bmatrix}2 & i & j & k\end{bmatrix}$ then, to be orthogonal to rows 4, 5, and 6, $i,\ j,\ k$ must be a permutation of $1,\ 2,\ 3$.  But all permutations are equivalent since permutation of $i, j,\ k$—or, more properly, permutation of the corresponding column sets—accompanied by the corresponding permutation of rows 1, 2, 3 leaves the matrix in the standard form above.  So we take the lexicographically minimal permutation and let row 7 be $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

To complete rows 8 and 9, we likewise need permutations of $1,\ 2,\ 3$, but to be orthogonal to row 7, these permutations must actually be derangements of $1, 2,\ 3$.  They must also be derangements of each other so that rows 8 and 9 are orthogonal.  From this we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
3\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

It remains to complete rows 10, 11, and 12.  Orthogonality with rows 4, 5, and 6 requires that each of these rows be completed with a permutation of $1,\ 2,\ 3$.  Orthogonality with rows 7, 8, and 9 requires that the permutation have exactly one element in common position with each of the permutations used in those rows.  The permutations used in rows 10, 11, and 12 must also be derangements of each other so that those rows are pairwise mutually orthogonal.  There are only three permutations of $1$, $2$, $3$ that haven't yet been used, and they exactly fit the bill.  Therefore we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
3 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The resulting matrix is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & -\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & -\\
1 & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & -\\
1 & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & 1\\
\hline
- & 1 & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1\\
- & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & - & -\\
- & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & -\\
\hline
- & - & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & 1 & -\\
- & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & - & - & - & 1\\
- & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & -
\end{array}\right].
$$
Now negate columns 7-12 and rows 7-12.  This amounts to negating the four $3\times3$ blocks in the upper right corner and the four $3\times3$ blocks in the lower left corner.  The result is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & - & -\\
\hline
1 & - & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & - & 1 & 1\\
1 & - & - & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & 1 & 1 & - & 1\\
1 & - & - & - & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & 1 & 1 & -\\
\hline
1 & - & 1 & - & 1 & 1 & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1\\
1 & - & 1 & 1 & - & 1 & - & - & 1 & 1 & - & -\\
1 & - & 1 & 1 & 1 & - & 1 & - & - & - & 1 & -\\
\hline
1 & 1 & - & - & 1 & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & 1 & -\\
1 & 1 & - & 1 & - & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & 1\\
1 & 1 & - & 1 & 1 & - & - & 1 & - & 1 & - & -
\end{array}\right].
$$

This construction shows that, up to equivalence, there is a unique solution since at no point were there two or more non-equivalent ways to add the next row.

Comment: Thank you Will, it is great answer. I'm trying to follow your approach. in each new row starting from 4th row and 4th column, we add new row but not a new block, right!

Comment: Yes, I am adding one row at a time, not one block.  I will expand the answer.

Comment: Will, in the matrix row no. 4 and no. 6 they violate condition P4 and P5. I'm trying to follow the whole approach, so this is my first notes

Comment: My overall approach is the following: ignore conditions P1-P5. Instead, focus on constructing a matrix with orthogonal rows. Once that is done, negate any columns that have $-1$ in the first row and negate any rows that have $-1$ in the first column. These negations preserve orthogonality and so the result will be a matrix with orthogonal rows and first row and column all $1$s. But a matrix with first row and column all $1$s and orthogonal rows must satisfy conditions P1-P5. In particular, all rows but the first will have six $1$s and six $-1$s because that...

Comment: ...is the only way they can be orthogonal to row 1.  In addition, you can prove that any two rows of such a matrix (apart from the first) will have three $1$s in common position and three $-1$s in common position.

Comment: The advantage of my setup is that in rows 4-12, each set of three columns in the column partition contains exactly one $1$.  If you stick with the original five conditions, then two of the sets contain exactly one $1$ and two of the sets contain exactly two $1$s.  This complicates the description slightly.

Comment: I see that your design is really good and it achieves the orthogonality between every rows and every column, and you claim that this design is non-isomorphic so there must be a mapping from this design to say Paley's Construction. So, in your design in order to improve it, we need only to find a trick of the mapping from only 2 values of -1s in each row to values of 1s. (including some restriction such as first row and first column has a 1 value) Then we will achieves the condition of in the question. I like this idea, but finding a good mapping is difficult job!! Ammm

Comment: If you multiply every element of column 7 by -1, the rows of the matrix will remain pairwise mutually orthogonal, and you will have changed one of the $-1$ elements in the first row to $1$.  You can do the same thing for all six of the columns that have $-1$ in row 1.  If you do that, you will change three  $-1$s in row 2 to $1$s while changing three $1$s to $-1$s, resulting in no net change in the number of $-1$s.  The same applies to row 3.  In row 4, you will change four $-1$s to $1$s and two $1$s to $-1$s, resulting in a net decrease of two $-1$s.  The same applies to rows 5 - 12.